# Is it possible to recover snaps if ubuntu fails to start?

Tags: 18.04, data-recovery, snap

Recently I faced a havoc when I clicked on Upgrade button and ubuntu failed to start. I had to backup entire HDD but I could restore applications to its previous state. I had to install and reconfigure everything.

Snapstore seems a promising initiative. As I was reading more about it, I noticed all apps are stored as snap file under `/var/lib/snapd/` while user configurations are stored in `~/snap/`

If my system crashes this time, will it be possible for me to restore applications from `/var/lib/snapd/` and `~/snap` folder ?

Comment: Have you had this problem before? Or are you generally asking if you can just copy everything from `/var/lib/snapd` and `~/snap` from one system to another, as a backup/transfer? Try booting a live ISO and copy/link/mount those folders & see what happens?

Comment: generally asking ! Ok I will try and post here